# The difference in the speed of copying from the buffer

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I cannot understand the reason why the copy speed varies so much in these examples. I get Almost indetical images from them. Calculation time is also faster on 'faster' variant

Didn't help:
move all the variables of the 'slow' variant inside the kernel, various memory flags almost do not change the result.

It turns out the problem is in the kernel, but what exactly is the problem?

WARNING! I pasted the whole file

```py
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import time
```

Faster variant. It takes ~0.15s to copy from buffer

```py
width = 800
height = 800
X = 0
Y = 0
R = 2
maxiter = 80000

xmin = X - R
xmax = X + R
ymin = Y - R
ymax = Y + R

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

r1 = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, width, dtype=np.float64)
r2 = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, height, dtype=np.float64)
q = r1 + r2[:, None] * 1j
q = np.ravel(q)
output = np.empty(width*height, dtype=np.uint8)

mf = cl.mem_flags
q_opencl = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=q)
output_opencl = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, output.nbytes)

prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
    __kernel void mandelbrot(__global double2 *q,
                     __global uchar *output, ushort const maxiter)
    {
        int gid = get_global_id(0);
        double nreal, real = 0;
        double imag = 0;
        output[gid] = 0.0;

        int curiter = 0;
        for(curiter = 0; curiter < maxiter; curiter++) {
            nreal = real*real - imag*imag + q[gid].x;
            imag = 2* real*imag + q[gid].y;
            real = nreal;
            if (real*real + imag*imag > 4.0f){
                break;
            }
        }
        if (curiter < maxiter) {
            output[gid] = curiter*64;
        }
    }
    """).build()

prg.mandelbrot(queue, output.shape, None, q_opencl, output_opencl, np.uint16(maxiter))

t0 = time.time()
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, output, output_opencl).wait()
print(time.time()-t0, 'copy')

output = output.reshape((width, height))
```

Slower variant. It takes ~0.78s to copy from buffer

```py
size = (800, 800)
X = 0
Y = 0
R = 2
maxiter = 80000

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

output = np.empty(size[0]*size[1], dtype=np.uint8)

mf = cl.mem_flags
output_cl = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, output.nbytes)

prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
    __kernel void mandelbrot(
        __global uchar *out,
        int width,
        int height,
        double real,
        double imag,
        double const radius,
        int const maxiter) {
            int id = get_global_id(0);

            int i = id % width;
            int j = id / width;

            double window_radius = (width < height) ? width : height;
            double x0 = real + radius * (2 * i - (float)width) / window_radius;
            double y0 = imag - radius * (2 * j - (float)height) / window_radius;
            double x = 0;
            double y = 0;

            int n = 0;
            double x_temp = 0;
            for(n = 0; n < maxiter; n++)
            {
                x_temp = x*x - y*y + x0;
                y = 2 * x*y + y0;
                x = x_temp;
                if (x*x + y*y > 4.0f){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (n < maxiter) {
                out[id] = n*64;
            }
            else {
                out[id] = 0;
            }
    }
""").build()

prg.mandelbrot(queue, output.shape, None,
                output_cl,
                np.int32(size[0]),
                np.int32(size[1]),
                np.float64(X),
                np.float64(Y),
                np.float64(R),
                np.int32(maxiter),
                )

t0 = time.time()
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, output, output_cl).wait()
print(time.time() - t0, 'copy')

output = output.reshape((size[1], size[0]))
```

Comment: Is calling kernel blocking or is it separated than copy?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik sorry, i cant understand what you want to ask( I just want to khow the way it works, and why exactly it takes more time to copy identical array. Its hard to find out in documentation, i need someone, who's a good judge of opencl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot understand the reason why the copy speed varies so much in these examples.

The reason is: you're not measuring the time of the copy command.

You say "prg.mandelbrot() executes the kernel and do all the calculations" - that's not what it does. It *enqueues* the kernel. Then you *enqueue* the copy command, and then you call `wait()`. Some implementations start executing immediately after enqueue, but some do not start until you call `clFinish/clFlush/clWaitForEvents` (the last is what PyOpenCL's `Event.wait()` does - in your code, `cl.enqueue_copy()` returns an event).

The problem is that you're doing the beginner mistake of trying to measure OpenCL (GPU) time using host CPU time. It never works. You have to measure on-GPU time via OpenCL event profiling. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598214/time-measuring-in-pyopencl) how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In first version you are giving 80000 to maxiter which is unsigned short. Max 65535. Overflows and wraps around to 14k ish value.

Second version you have int which is 32bit. 80k passes correctly.

14.5k / 80.0k iterations

0.15 / 0.78 seconds

Consistent

Comment: Yeah, that's stupid mistake, thx. But why copying from buffer depends on iterations amount? prg.mandelbrot() executes the kernel and do all the calculations resulting in same uint8 array in 800iters and 80000iters cases. Even if i fill the array with 0 and 1 it takes more time with more iterations. Or cl.enqueue_copy() somehow executes the kernel? I will be very grateful for the help.

Comment: I asked it on comment. I tried to mean "is kernel execution synchronized before buffer copy". You are waiting only on copy operation. But you are not waiting for kernel operation. I guess either copy is a "map" operation because it is an integrated gpu(hence, zero-copy) or the kernel time is too high compared to copy time and adds to it because you didn't sync before copy.